# convertir array en objetoJson

Tags: php, array

Tengo este array con otros arrays dentro
La idea era crear algo como un objeto JSON

Pero al intentar devolver el primer nombre, me sale un error.

```
    $capitales = [["id"=>1,"nombre"=>"Trinidad"],
    ["id"=>32,"Sucre"=>"marco"],
    ["id"=>69,"nombre"=>"Cochabamba"],
    ["id"=>160,"nombre"=>"La Paz"],
    ["id"=>188,"nombre"=>"Oruro"],
    ["id"=>229,"nombre"=>"Cobija"],
    ["id"=>270,"nombre"=>"Potosi"],
    ["id"=>274,"nombre"=>"Santa Cruz de la Sierra"],
    ["id"=>334,"nombre"=>"Tarija"]];

    
    foreach ($capitales as $capital) {
       return $capital->nombre;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente estoy haciendo algo mal, pero no se que podria ser...

Answer (score 1):

para pasa de un array a Json hay muchas manejas

1. el uso de array me permite tener una mejor organización, y puedo anida los array tipo arbol
2. usa un foreach y añadir los datos
3. tambien puede usa **JSON Formatter - Chrome**

public function leerJosn()
{

```
$capitales = [
  array('id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'marcos'),
  array('id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'marcos'),
  array('id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'marcos', 'data' =>  array('id' => 344, 'estado' => 23),),
];
//correo los datos en un foreach y añadir el array
foreach ($capitales as $key => $value) {
  $capitales[$key]['dataForaneo'] = array('id' => 2323, 'subEstado' => 'procesando');
}
header("Content-Type: application/json");
return json_encode($capitales);
```

}

el resultado se muestra en la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es convertir a objetos tanto el array principal como todos los arrays que contiene, para luego generar un **json** que sea **solo de objectos**, puedes hacerlo así:

```
$capitales = json_encode((object) json_decode(json_encode($capitales), false));
```

donde:

- `json_encode($capitales)`: Convierte a **json** el array `$capitales` gracias a la función [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)
- `json_decode(x, false)`: convierte el *json* representado por `x` a **objeto** gracias al uso de la función [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) y a su parámetro `false` (de hecho es el valor por omisión, pero así nos aseguramos), que dicho parámetro fuerza la conversión de los arrays asociativos a objetos.

El problema ahora es que no ha convertido el array principal, solo los arrays internos asociativos, por lo tanto aún queda algo más por hacer, que es:

- `(object) X`: que convierte el array, representado por una **X**, a objeto, tal como indica su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)

Todo eso combinado tal como se muestra más arriba consigue que tanto el array padre como todos sus descendientes (en este caso) se conviertan a objetos en PHP, lo cual no parece tener demasiado sentido pues la forma de recorrerlo seria con un `foreach()` también, pero coje todo el sentido del mundo cuando finalmente lo volvemos a convertir a **json** englobándolo todo en otro `json_encode`:

```
json_encode((object) json_decode(json_encode($capitales), false));
```

Si finalmente hacemos un echo de $capitales, después de la instrucción, de este modo:

```
$capitales = [["id"=>1,"nombre"=>"Trinidad"],
    ["id"=>32,"nombre"=>"marco"],
    ["id"=>69,"nombre"=>"Cochabamba"],
    ["id"=>160,"nombre"=>"La Paz"],
    ["id"=>188,"nombre"=>"Oruro"],
    ["id"=>229,"nombre"=>"Cobija"],
    ["id"=>270,"nombre"=>"Potosi"],
    ["id"=>274,"nombre"=>"Santa Cruz de la Sierra"],
    ["id"=>334,"nombre"=>"Tarija"]];

$capitales = json_encode((object) json_decode(json_encode($capitales), false));

echo $capitales;
```

nos devuelve este json lleno de objetos y sin arrays:

> {"0":{"id":1,"nombre":"Trinidad"},"1":{"id":32,"nombre":"marco"},"2":{"id":69,"nombre":"Cochabamba"},"3":{"id":160,"nombre":"La
> Paz"},"4":{"id":188,"nombre":"Oruro"},"5":{"id":229,"nombre":"Cobija"},"6":{"id":270,"nombre":"Potosi"},"7":{"id":274,"nombre":"Santa
> Cruz de la Sierra"},"8":{"id":334,"nombre":"Tarija"}}